# can't get value from readonly or disabled textbox control asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, null

I created an uneditable control in asp.net using either of the folowing

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
or
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" readonly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

am using a javascript popup to fill the textbox in the client side. the value is always null when i tried to retrieve it in codebehind

can anyone suggest a better way

Comment: Just a suggestion for you, if the value is readonly all the time, why not have it as a hidden field on the form, and use the <asp:label/> command to show the JS value while populating the hidden field.

Comment: thanks, this is sure another way

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind

```
 txtStartDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Read more about [How to retrieve read-only textbox's value in the code behind](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-retrieve-readonly-textboxs-value-in-the-code-behind-924.php)

Comment: i found a solution, by using a premade web control instead, thanks for responding

Comment: @huMpty duMpty: I just ran across this problem while converting an old app (2005 VB to 2010 C#) and the odd part is, it worked fine in the old version.  Is this just an issue with new versions?

Comment: @Limey: actually I am not quite sure about that

Comment: @huMpty duMpty: It worked for me too, but after removing `readonly="true"`. Just set the attribute of the textbox. +1 for the link, got the hint from the link.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty what if the read only is a column of a gridview?
when the column is not readonly i use `prIDUpdate = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;` but this doesn't work when I add `readonly=true` to the column

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" readonly="true"></asp:TextBox>`

**you can use this way**

`txtStartDate.Text = Request.Form[txtStartDate.UniqueID];`