# When a textbox is disabled on the client slide, it loses its value on the server side. Is there a work around it?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a text box and a checkbox on a webform.  When the checkbox is checked, it disables the Text box on the client side.

```
txtBox.disabled = chkDisable.checked;
```

Then when I try to read the TextBox's Text property on the server side, it is blank when it is disabled.  When it is not disabled, the Text property has what it shows on the screen.  When the box is disabled, its value is not being saved to the ViewState.

Is there a work around it?

Comment: Make it readonly instead of disabled. and then you can read the values like [get value from readonly or disabled textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10227072/3796048)

Comment: That is a normal behavior of forms. It will not submit disabled controls to server. To make this work make this field read only or create a hidden field that holds the value of this textbox

Comment: readOnly does it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is a Server Side Solution as you asked for work around
you can go with the `CheckBox_ChangeEvent`  in that event

```
//Pseudo code
if(checkbox.checked)
{
 txtBox.Enabled =false;
}else{
txtBox.Enabled =true;
}
```

Comment: A server side solution is not an option.